# Сохранение десериализованного агрегата Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine2

Бекенд по API получает многоуровневую структуру, например договор и добавленные к нему некие файлы:

```
{
   "id": 23,
   "number":"Д-23",
   "dateStart":"2019-12-12",
   "dateEnd":"2020-01-12",
   "files": [
      {
         "id":1,
         "url":"http://...",
         "type":"ЕГРП",
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "url":"http://...",
         "type":"ЕГРЮЛ",
      }
   ]
}
```

Эта структура ранее была получена клиентом, немного модифицирована(файлы например добавил или dateEnd поменял) и прислана для сохранения.
Я эту структуру десериализую в объект агрегат Contract со всеми необходимыми вложенностями.
Сохранение через простой вызов

```
/** @var Contract $contract */
$entityManager->persist($contract);
$entityManager->flush();
```

ни к чему не приведет, а точнее **приведет к ошибке**, т.к. доктрина подумает, что я хочу добавить новый объект, в тот момент, когда **я пытаюсь обновить существующий**.
Есть ли в доктрине функционал, решающий данную проблему?

Comment: Ну если вы хотите обновить существующий, то вам нужно его предварительно получить, мне думается. При получении сущности она попадает в Unit Of Work и именно по этому знает про то, что ее обновляют. Возможен наверняка вариант работы на более низком уровне (всегда остается вариант делать нативные запросы к БД), но и вероятно стоит посмотреть в сторону работы именно с UOW. Хотя есть ощущение что эта задача весьма востребована и существуют весьма стандартные решения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> а точнее приведет к ошибке, т.к. доктрина подумает, что я хочу добавить новый объект, в тот момент, когда я пытаюсь обновить существующий.

Специально для этого случая в Doctrine существует операция [EntityManager#merge($entity)](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities). Вот часть документации, описывающая действия для Вашего случая:

> Объединение сущностей относится к объединению (обычно отсоединенных) сущностей в контекст EntityManager, чтобы они снова стали управляемыми. Чтобы объединить состояние объекта в EntityManager, используйте метод EntityManager#merge($entity). Состояние переданного объекта будет объединено в управляемую копию этого объекта, и эта копия впоследствии будет возвращена.
>
> Пример:

```php
<?php
$detachedEntity = unserialize($serializedEntity); // some detached entity
$entity = $em->merge($detachedEntity);
// $entity now refers to the fully managed copy returned by the merge operation.
// The EntityManager $em now manages the persistence of $entity as usual.
```

> Когда вы хотите сериализовать/десериализовать сущности, вы должны сделать все свойства сущностей protected, а не private. Причина этого в том, что если вы сериализовали класс, который ранее был экземпляром прокси, закрытые переменные не будут сериализованы, а PHP выдаст Warning.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Уже опробовал, но к сожалению данный метод объявлен deprecated

Comment: @ДенисНестерюк, я про выход третьей доктрины слышу не первый год. Но она все еще "upcoming". Сейчас Вы по любому используете вторую версию, так что вполне себе рабочее решение. А по поводу deprecated - альтернатива появится только в новой версии, так что "доки сонце встане - роса очі виїсть". Для перехода на третью доктрину по любому придется делать отдельный рефакторинг всего проекта, тогда и это заодно поправите. IMHO.

Comment: По крайней мере, я через неделю использую это решение в одном из своих проектов. Искал целенаправленно для него. :)

Comment: Да, все верно уже использую)